# How do you jump the gap in Threat Level Apricot?

Tags: broforce

I'm trying to get over the gap just after the zipline in Threat Level: Apricot, but no matter which Bro I use, none of them can make the jump.

**How do I get past that gap?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Begin sprinting *while on the zipline*.  Stay sprinting once you dismount and you'll maintain enough momentum to make the jump.